# Does this filtration have a name?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-filtering

In the context of Ethier&Kurtz *Markov Processes: Characterization and Convergence* (Chapter 4, equation (3.2)) as well as the two papers [*Martingale problems for conditional distributions of Markov processes*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-probability/volume-3/issue-none/Martingale-Problems-for-Conditional-Distributions-of-Markov-Processes/10.1214/EJP.v3-31.full) (last paragraph on page 2, just before equation (1.2)) and [*The filtered martingale problem*](https://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/nappo/LAVORI/Kurtz-Nappo-fmgp-2009-Oxford-Handbook-Filtering.pdf) (last sentence of Section 1), I have come across the filtration $(\hat{\mathcal{F}}^X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ given as the completion of
$$
\sigma\left(\int_0^r h(X_t)\;ds \;:\; h\text{ bounded measurable }, r\leq t\right).
$$
Now, Problem 2 of Chapter 2 in Ethier&Kurtz claims that this filtration is not very different from the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}^X_t := \sigma(X_s\;:\; s\leq t)$ in the sense that they only differ by null sets.
Furthermore, it appears that $\hat{\mathcal{F}}^X_t \subseteq \mathcal{F}^X_t$ whenever $X$ is progressively measurable, with equality for almost every $t\geq 0$. If $X$ is càdlàg with no fixed point continuity, equality holds for every $t\geq 0$. (For these statements, see e.g. the [Appendix A.1 of *The filtered martingale problem*](https://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/nappo/LAVORI/Kurtz-Nappo-fmgp-2009-Oxford-Handbook-Filtering.pdf).

For special types of problems, this seems to be the preferred filtration, especially as it agrees with the classical one for most processes of interest.
I was not, however, able to find the origin of this filtration and whether it has a special name or not.
I would be very happy about any further reference that makes use of this filtration!